# Oracle PLS-00357 error when executing procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

This is the code of my procedure:

```
drop procedure CREATE_SEQUENTIAL_TR;
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure CREATE_SEQUENTIAL_TR(table_name_pr VARCHAR)
is
    coluna_cod varchar(100 char);
begin
    select 
        COLUMN_NAME 
    into
        coluna_cod
    from 
        ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
    where 
        TABLE_NAME = table_name_pr 
        and COLUMN_NAME like 'PK_CD%';

    execute immediate '
    drop sequence cod_' || table_name_pr ||';
    create sequence cod_' || table_name_pr ||';';

    execute immediate '
    drop trigger cod_' || table_name_pr || '_tr;
    create or replace trigger cod_' || table_name_pr || '_tr            
    before 
        UPDATE or INSERT on ' || table_name_pr || '
    for each row
    begin
        if UPDATING then
            if :new.' || coluna_cod ||' != :old.' || coluna_cod ||' then
                :new.' || coluna_cod ||' := :old.' || coluna_cod ||';
            end if;
        else -- inserting
            :new.' || coluna_cod ||' := cod_' || table_name_pr || '.nextval();
        end if; 
    end;';
end;
```

The error is when I execute it :

```
--test_trigger_cod is a table name
execute create_sequential_tr(test_trigger_cod)
```

The error is

> PLS-00357: Table, View Or Sequence reference 'test_trigger_cod' not
>   allowed in this context

It seems that I can't use the parameter inside the where? What's the workaround?

Full error (manually translated) :

```
Error starting from line : 1 on the command -
BEGIN create_sequential_tr(teste_trigger_cod); END;
Error report: -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 28:
PLS-00357: Reference 'TESTE_TRIGGER_COD' to Table, View ou Sequence not allowed in this context
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: And what line of code, and where is test_trigger_cod defined and what is the value?

Comment: @OldProgrammer updated with full trace

Comment: if `table_name_pr` is a varchar, you need quotes when you provide it.  This, `execute create_sequential_tr(test_trigger_cod)` should be this: `execute create_sequential_tr('test_trigger_cod')`

Comment: @DanBracuk When I tried that it gave `ORA-00911 identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual`

Comment: Id' take the 2nd Execute immediate and have it write to a variable first then write out the variable to an output window then execute it.  then in the output windwo you can see if the PLSQL is well formed.

Comment: @xQbert Care to post as answer? To be honest I patched this together using examples found, I have no real clue what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE runs a single SQL statement. You are trying to execute multiple statements per call. So you need to turn this ...

```
execute immediate '
    drop sequence cod_' || table_name_pr ||';
    create sequence cod_' || table_name_pr ||';';
```

... into this:

```
execute immediate 'drop sequence cod_' || table_name_pr ;
execute immediate 'create sequence cod_' || table_name_pr ;
```

Do the same with the trigger statements.

As a general observation, dynamic SQL is hard because compilation errors become runtime errors. Make it easy on yourself, and use variables to assemble the statements; this approach gives you something which supports debugging e.g:

```
l_stmt := 'drop sequence cod_' || table_name_pr ;
dbms_output.put_line('about to execute :: ' || l_stmt);
execute immediate l_stmt ;
```

Comment: This solved the issue, in the end I also needed to add AUTHID CURRENT_USER to work with the execute immediates